# Number of 9-digit number satisfying the conditions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many 9-digit numbers containing exactly two 4s and three 5s and not containing any 0s are there?

Answer (score 3):

If you take 5 things and place them in 9 spaces, there are $9 \choose 5$ ways to do that. But the two 4s are indistinguishable, as are the three 5s, so $\frac{1}{2!3!}$ of those ways are the same.

Once you've done that, there are 4 spaces left for other digits. Since you can't use 0, 4 or 5, there are 7 different digits you can place in each of those spaces.

That should be enough information for you to put everything together.